# Setting to stop LaTeX from fitting content to page by stretching spacing

Tags: spacing

I'm using a template for my thesis and now that I'm all done I want to set a formatting parameter different from the one in the template.
When an image is supposed to show and it doesn't fit in the end of a page, it goes to the next page and the content in that previous page doesn't occupy a full page.
The problem is that when that happens, LaTeX strecthes the spacing in the page so that the content fits the whole page, like so:

[image]

When I want it to keep the normal spacing, like so :

[image]

What command could be causing this? Or what would avoid it? I've Ctrl+F'ed \flushbottom and \raggedbottom and the only two entries I found made no difference so I really don't know what's causing this. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Turns I shouldn't be looking for `\raggedbottom`, but rather **putting in the preamble**